# UWP FormsComboBox and FormsTextBox Styling within Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am using Xamarin Forms to create a POC app that runs on UWP, and the UWP XAML styling has me at a loss.

Could anyone please advise how to apply a similar style to the Picker (FormsComboBox in UWP) and Editor (which now that I look at it, may be the same as FormsTextBox which is what is used for the Entry, so that may be an easy one) as is done here for the Entry in [UWP XAML](https://github.com/microsoft/SmartHotel360-Mobile/blob/master/Source/SmartHotel.Clients/SmartHotel.Clients.UWP/App.xaml#L14) and a [CustomRenderer](https://github.com/microsoft/SmartHotel360-Mobile/blob/master/Source/SmartHotel.Clients/SmartHotel.Clients.UWP/Renderers/ExtendedEntryRenderer.cs).

Among other things, it gets rid of the left, top, and right border and weird default UWP background and just leaves a bottom border (to be colored as per the introduced LineColor property set on the control).

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone please advise how to apply a similar style to the Picker

Please check [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/PickerStyle.xaml) in **Xamarin** source code. And it has declare `FormsComboBox` style in the `PickerStyle.xaml` file, please copy it to your `App.xaml`(uwp client project) and edit base on your requirement. And please note `FormsComboBox` removed `EditableText` that use to input the matched text in native combobox control.